# Using jquery to render html from an action within an area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a jquery click method that looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clickView(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Jac/ViewCustomDetails",
            data: { productId: dataItem.Id },
            success: function (response) {
                $("#details").html(response);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                document.write(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Basically this makes an AJAX call to my controller to render an action.

The action `ViewCustomDetails`, which is within `JacController`, and within an area looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult ViewCustomDetails(int productId)
    {
        Detail model;

        model = new Detail
        {
            Price = productId.ToString(),
            Origin = productId.ToString()
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

When I click on my button that fires off the AJAX call, I am able to break into my action. however I get this error in my view

```
The view 'ViewCustomDetails' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Jac/ViewCustomDetails.aspx
~/Views/Jac/ViewCustomDetails.ascx
~/Views/Shared/ViewCustomDetails.aspx
~/Views/Shared/ViewCustomDetails.ascx
~/Views/Jac/ViewCustomDetails.cshtml
~/Views/Jac/ViewCustomDetails.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/ViewCustomDetails.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/ViewCustomDetails.vbhtml
```

Obviously there's no such controller/action in my views folder as my controller is within an area.

How do I get it to reference the controller in my area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to add the area name into my URL in the jquery code as such

```
url: "/Dan/Jac/ViewCustomDetails",
```

instead of just

```
url: "/Jac/ViewCustomDetails",
```

Answer (score 0):

It IS referencing your controller but the line `return View(model);` in your ViewCustomDetails method requires the existence of a View file, which would normally be called ViewCustomDetails.cshtml

This View file must take a model type of `Detail`

You might also need to JSONify the returning view.